# How to make Top and bottom view using ext js chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I am trying to make Amount and Month graph using ext js chart plugin where the month should come in the top and the amount should come in the bottom, I am successfully able to bring that view but the **issue is, amount is changing to decimal value**

here is the left(Amount) and bottom(Month) view

http://jsfiddle.net/djaydxnd/52/

here is what I am tring to bring, bottom(Amount) and top(Month) view

http://jsfiddle.net/djaydxnd/51/

**Here is the code**

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.chart.Chart'
]);

Ext.define('CricketScore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['month', 'data1' ]
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'CricketScore',
            data: [
                { month: 'Jan', data1: 20 },
                { month: 'Feb', data1: 20 },
                { month: 'Mar', data1: 19 },
                { month: 'Apr', data1: 18 },
                { month: 'May', data1: 18 },
                { month: 'Jun', data1: 17 },
                { month: 'Jul', data1: 16 },
                { month: 'Aug', data1: 16 },
                { month: 'Sep', data1: 16 },
                { month: 'Oct', data1: 16 },
                { month: 'Nov', data1: 15 },
                { month: 'Dec', data1: 15 }
            ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
   renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
   width: 400,
   height: 300,
   theme: 'Green',
   store: store,
    animate: true,
   axes: [
       {
                type: 'Numeric',
                position: 'bottom',
                fields: ['data1'],
                minimum: 0
            }, {
                type: 'Category',
                position: 'top',
                fields: ['month'],
            }
    ],

      series: [
       {
                type: 'column',
                axis: 'left',
                xField: 'month',
                yField: 'data1',
                style: {
                    opacity: 0.80
                },
                highlight: {
                    fill: '#000',
                    'stroke-width': 20,
                    stroke: '#fff'
                },
                tips: {
                    trackMouse: true,
                    style: 'background: #FFF',
                    height: 20,
                    renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                        this.setTitle(storeItem.get('month') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data1') + '%');
                    }
                }
            }
    ]
});
```

If you check for **"position"** it will be in **"axes: [ ]"** array list

**Update in Question**

the bottom graph values will be custom values, a have shared my expected image.

[image: click here for expected graph sample]

Comment: Try adding a maximum :20 to the numeric axes

Comment: /**
         * @cfg {Number} maximum 
         * The maximum value drawn by the axis. If not set explicitly, the axis
         * maximum will be calculated automatically.
         */
        maximum: NaN,

Comment: @Couponrabais your logic is right, but sorry I was wrong in my question, now what I am looking is, the bottom graph values will be custom values, I have shared my expected image.

Answer (score 0):

`Column Chart` can not be use with `top axis` and `bottom axis`  for that you have to use `Bar Chart`.

```
    series: [
           {
                    type: 'bar',
                    ...
           }
```

Please refer this [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/example/charts/Bar.html).

In general all charts has to have one vertical line(left/right) and one horizontal line(top/bottom) by that way only you can identify connection points which is essential to create any charts.